# Hierarchical query to show all children under each parent

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Please see the attached images:

**Visual Diagram of Tree**

[image: Visual diagram of hirarchy]

**Desired Query Output**

[image: Desired query output]

As an example, this is the structure of the data as shown in image (diagram). I need a query that will show the same result in the second image (to show all the children under each parent).

Below is the code I tried (the results are not like what I'm looking for):

```
 SELECT parent,
        LEVEL,
        child

FROM  table1 

CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parent = PRIOR child;
```

Comment: What is your current code producing as output?

Answer (score 4):

I altered the column names in your table from "CHILD" and "PARENT" to "ID" and "PARENT_ID", respectively, to be a little less confusing.

Anyway, you need to use **`CONNECT_BY_ROOT(parent_id)`** to get what is being shown as "PARENT" in your desired output.  If you do not care about the order of the rows in your result, this is simply:

```
SELECT connect_by_root(parent_id) "PARENT", id "CHILD"
FROM   table1
WHERE  connect_by_root(parent_id) is not null
CONNECT BY parent_id = prior id
```

If you do care about the order of the rows, it gets harder.  You need to check the depth of each node in the tree and use that to order your results.  That would be:

```
with hier as ( 
SELECT connect_by_root(parent_id) root_id, id, level, 
       case when connect_by_root(parent_id) is null then level else null end root_depth
FROM   table1
CONNECT BY parent_id = prior id
)
select h1.root_id "PARENT", h1.id "CHILD"
from hier h1 inner join hier h2 on h2.root_id is null and h2.id = h1.root_id
order by h2.root_depth, h1.root_id, h1.id
```

Here is a full example, with test data:

```
WITH table1 ( id, parent_id ) AS
( SELECT 'A', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A11', 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A12', 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A21', 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A121', 'A12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A122', 'A12' FROM DUAL ),
-- Solution begins here 
hier as ( 
SELECT connect_by_root(parent_id) root_id, id, level lvl, 
       case when connect_by_root(parent_id) is null then level else null end root_depth
FROM   table1
CONNECT BY parent_id = prior id
)
select h1.root_id "PARENT", h1.id "CHILD", h2.*
from hier h1 inner join hier h2 on h2.root_id is null and h2.id = h1.root_id
order by h2.root_depth, h1.root_id, h1.lvl, h1.id
```

> ```
> +--------+-------+
> | PARENT | CHILD |
> +--------+-------+
> | A      | A1    |
> | A      | A2    |
> | A      | A3    |
> | A      | A11   |
> | A      | A12   |
> | A      | A21   |
> | A      | A121  |
> | A      | A122  |
> | A1     | A11   |
> | A1     | A12   |
> | A1     | A121  |
> | A1     | A122  |
> | A2     | A21   |
> | A12    | A121  |
> | A12    | A122  |
> +--------+-------+
> ```

Comment: @Mattew McPeak thanks alot. This error message is showing when I try to filter the output data:"Connect by loop in user data"?

Comment: Add `NOCYCLE` after the `CONNECT BY` as you had in your post.  Your sample data did not have any loops, so I omitted it.

Comment: @Mattew McPewhak  I want to filter based on the Parent (A as an example) and to show the children under this parent. In the results, when I filter based on one parent will show just the direct children not the children of the children and so on.... really need help . thanks again.

Comment: You should just need to add `START WITH parent_id = whatever` to the 1st query in my answer.  You don't need the more complicated version because if you are just filtering on one parent, you don't have to worry about ordering the 1st column of your output.